# Django/Python caching solution that I can access with complex keys rather than only strings

Tags: python, django

It is my understanding that all caching solutions for Django/Python are essentially based on key/value dictionaries.

```
cache.store(“key”, “value”)

cache.get(“key”) # <- “value”
```

I understand there are decorators and other abstractions that allow you to store in cache based on the view function, but they’re agnostic towards the inputs of this function (POST/GET parameters, for example).

Here’s my problem: I need to cache results of computations of complex sets of inputs, including (but not limited to), the user that’s performing the request, dictionaries, booleans, ecc...

I could, in theory, serialize these inputs into a string and use this string as the key for caching but I was wondering if there are some pre-made solutions to solve this problem.

Something like this:

```
def my_view(request):

    output = cache.get(request, None)
    if output is None:
        output = complex_stuff(request) # <- can be serialized as string
        cache.store(request, output)
```

Or, even better, where I can use an arbitrary dictionary as a key, instead of a string.

This is not merely caching per user ([Django per user view caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146741/django-per-user-view-caching)). Caching per user would be insufficient as I need it per user *and* per user input.

Comment: Yeah, creating keys by stringifying the parameters is an okay choice. But each character is 1 byte, so if the keys are too long and you have very limited RAM, you can generate unique keys by hashing the string. The resulting hash will always be of a fixed size. MD5 hash is an ideal choice here.

Comment: Yeah, I also thought about hashes, but I was a bit caught up with hashing a Python class. Didn't consider that it'd be "class -> string -> hash": that makes sense and I'll probably do it that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try this package, [django-cache-memoize](https://github.com/peterbe/django-cache-memoize), which auto memoize arguments and keyword arguments. Or if you use redis, and need more control, you can also try my package [Django-Cacheme](https://github.com/Yiling-J/django-cacheme)