# Django 1.11: disable cache for authentificated users

Tags: python, django, caching, authorization, django-grappelli

We have a legacy application written in python 2.7 and django 1.11 (and no resources to migrate). Also it uses `grappelli` for authorization. We tried to add `Edit` links for some pages (each of the pages displays detailed info on a `Round` object) that should be visible only for authorized users *with rights to edit a Round* ( `APPNAME | round | Can change round` in the `grappelli` web interface). In the template, the permission is checked like so:

```py
{% if perms.round.can_change_round %}
    &emsp;<a href="{{link_to_change_round}}" class="stuff-only-link">{% trans 'Edit' %}</a>
{% endif %}
```

The problem occurs when the following events take place in a short time interval:

1. A user which has the permission to edit a Round visits a page - and sees the `Edit` link.
2. A user which has no permission to edit a Round (e.g. anonymous user) visits **the same** page - and also sees the link!

Revelant settings (`settings.py`) are:

```py
CACHES = {
    'default': {
    #   'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.dummy.DummyCache',
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    }
}

SOLO_CACHE = 'default'
SOLO_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 5*60
```

When I change cache to `dummy`, the problem disappears. Thus, it seems to be an obvious solution to totally disable caching for authorized users. To be more precise:

a) If a user is anonymous (the most of real site users) - the requested page can be written to the cache and can be readed from the cache;

b) If a user is authorized (about 5-7 users) - the requested page can NOT be written to the cache and can NOT be readed from the cache.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: So how are you caching? [CacheMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache)? [Decorators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache)? [Fragments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching)?

Comment: It looks like we are using a decorators:

Comment: `@cache_page(cache_duration)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to @Melvin for the links to the documentation. After an hour of googling, an answer was found and adapted. The code is:

**EDIT**: Originally, the cache was function-based.
So, "/rounds/1" gave the same (cached) value as "/rounds/2".
We add the full URL to the cache key to fix the problem.

```py
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
'''
Python >= 2.4
Django >= 1.0

Author: eu@rafaelsdm.com
'''
# https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2524/
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146741/django-per-user-view-caching
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62913281/django-1-11-disable-cache-for-authentificated-users

from django.core.cache import cache

def cache_per_user(ttl=None, prefix=None):
    '''Decorador que faz cache da view pra cada usuario
    * ttl - Tempo de vida do cache, não enviar esse parametro significa que o
      cache vai durar até que o servidor reinicie ou decida remove-lo 
    * prefix - Prefixo a ser usado para armazenar o response no cache. Caso nao
      seja informado sera usado 'view_cache_'+function.__name__
    * cache_post - Informa se eh pra fazer cache de requisicoes POST
    * O cache para usuarios anonimos é compartilhado com todos
    * A chave do cache será uma das possiveis opcoes:
        '%s_%s'%(prefix, user.id)
        '%s_anonymous'%(prefix)
        'view_cache_%s_%s'%(function.__name__, user.id)
        'view_cache_%s_anonymous'%(function.__name__)
    '''
    def decorator(function):
        def apply_cache(request, *args, **kwargs):

            # No caching for authorized users:
            # they have to see the results of their edits immideately!

            can_cache = request.user.is_anonymous() and request.method == 'GET'

            # Gera a chave do cache
            if prefix:
                CACHE_KEY = '%s_%s'%(prefix, 'anonymous')
            else:
                CACHE_KEY = 'view_cache_%s_%s_%s'%(function.__name__, request.get_full_path(), 'anonymous')

            if can_cache:
                response = cache.get(CACHE_KEY, None)
            else:
                response = None

            if not response:
                print 'Not in cache: %s'%(CACHE_KEY)
                response = function(request, *args, **kwargs)
                if can_cache:
                    cache.set(CACHE_KEY, response, ttl)
            return response
        return apply_cache
    return decorator
```

and then in `views.py`:

```py
from cache_per_user import cache_per_user as cache_page
#...
#
#
@cache_page(cache_duration)
def round_detail(request, pk):
```

Answer (score 2):

You can fragment cache portions of your template and omit from cache parts that are related to user or cache them according to fragment variable state as [documented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/#template-fragment-caching)