# How to disable Django cache view for superuser?

Tags: django, caching

I use cache_page decorator for caching views in Django.

How can I disable cache for superuser or authorized users ?

Comment: Hope that It will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62913281/django-1-11-disable-cache-for-authentificated-users

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom decorator with the help of **`CacheMiddleware`** class as

```
from django.middleware.cache import CacheMiddleware
from django.utils.decorators import decorator_from_middleware_with_args


class CustomCacheMiddleware(CacheMiddleware):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            request._cache_update_cache = False
            return None
        return super().process_request(request)


def custom_cache_page(timeout, *, cache=None, key_prefix=None):
    return decorator_from_middleware_with_args(CustomCacheMiddleware)(
        cache_timeout=timeout, cache_alias=cache, key_prefix=key_prefix
    )


@custom_cache_page(60 * 15)
def my_view(request):
    ...
```