# Django caches user object

Tags: django, django-cache

Our websites sometimes has around 600 authenticated users trying to register for an event in a timeframe of 5 min. We have a VPS with 1 CPU and 1GB ram. On these moments the site slows down and gives a 502 error.

For that reason I'm using per-site cache with `FileBasedCache`. This works excellent and stress tests work fine.

But, when people login, they're redirect to their profile. This is the code:

```
class UserRedirectView(LoginRequiredMixin, RedirectView):

    permanent = False

    def get_redirect_url(self):
        return reverse("users:detail", kwargs={"membership_number": self.request.user.membership_number})
```

the user is redirect to an url with their membership_number

```
class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):

    model = User
    slug_field = "membership_number"
    slug_url_kwarg = "membership_number"
```

Some users are reporting that they are redirected to someone else his/her profile after logging in.

How does this work? How to prevent user specific parts of the website to be cached? e.g. users also see a list of events that are specific to the groups they are in. In other words, every user should see a different list.

Any ideas? Best practices?

Comment: Have you tried to use template cache in django ?

Comment: are you using @cache_page?

Comment: @Phteven I'm not using cache-page but per-site cache trough middleware.

Comment: @amadousow I would rather not use template cache, because I have loads of templates and I only would like to excluded the pages that use URL parameters.

Comment: Use the cache alongwith the `vary_on_cookie` decorator. See answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35682133/1925257.

Comment: Are you sure "membership_number" is unique? If so, in detail view, you use User model, is it the built-in Auth User model?  as this model has no membership _number field by default..if you can share your models and url so we can understand your case properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to vary cache on cookie so that logged in users (assuming cookie based auth) get another cache key.

```
from django.views.decorators.vary import vary_on_cookie
@vary_on_cookie
def my_view(request):
    pass
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#controlling-cache-using-other-headers
and
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#using-vary-headers